# Stack Overflow Careers gone?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, stack-exchange, careers-select

I once had a profile at SO Careers, similar to that of LinkeIn or a standard CV. I found it a much better alternative for a programmer to exercise her experience to the employer than LinkedIn, since it was possible to reference all the Q/A you have ever solver at SO.

Now the project is gone, disappeared without notice. I even had trouble to [acknowledge its existence](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-stack-overflow-careers). The main site [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) is redirected to [stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent](http://stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent) which seems to be of value to job hirers not seekers according to the [sign-up form](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/sign-up?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=so-talent&utm_term=login-page-sign-up&__hstc=104275039.954422545380bcaa1a87ab3597c83979.1523196465063.1523196465063.1523196465063.1&__hssc=104275039.7.443783783777445e%2026.1523196465064&__hsfp=1307982072).

Is the project gone? Should I revert back to LinkedIn and LinkedIn only to find a job in IT? I know they [are different](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-LinkedIn-and-Stack-Overflow-Careers), but SO is now the best value I have to show my prospective employer and I no more see no good way SO can help me achieve this goal.

Comment: Are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?

Comment: Redirecting to Talent from careers.stackoverflow.com sounds like an unwise decision

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1459339

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, that was what I was looking for :D. Thanks.